# How can I add function and array to already deployed contract on the main net

Tags: ethereum, solidity, go-ethereum

How can I add function and array to already deployed contract on the main net.

```
User[] public registeredArray;

function getAllUsers()public view returns(User[] memory){

return registeredArray;

}
```

---

How do I add this array to the struct of the deployed contract and also this new function to it?
Need to add to the deployed contract

Comment: Read the answer Upgradeable smart contracts here:  https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2404/upgradeable-smart-contracts - unless you are an expert in Solidity my suggestion is that you do not even try it, because it is out of your skill class.

Answer (score 2):

In short, you can't change deployed contract code.

Generally, you want to make your contract upgradeable the first time you deploy it, and even with that, you still need to deploy a new contract every time you want some sort of new functionality, what changes is basically that you have a proxy contract that stores the contract that is actually being used.

Worth to give a look at [writing-upgradeable](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/writing-upgradeable)